# How to use variable function-name in a loop?

Tags: php, loops

I have made this loop with PHP OOP:

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ 
echo "
    <tr>
    <td>$i</td>
    <td>".$menuSet->GetMenuLink1()."</td>
    <td>
        <a title='Edit' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>&nbsp; 
        <a title='Remove' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
";
// replace $menuSet->GetMenuLink1() with another variable
}
```

And as you can see I want to replace `$menuSet->GetMenuLink1()` variable with `$menuSet->GetMenuLink2()` and this loop goes till `$menuSet->GetMenuLink5()`.

(Add 1 to GetMenuLink function)

So how can I do this in php ?

Comment: It's a bad idea to have functions with such names.

Comment: create a single function and inside it do some sort of condition/case functionality to achieve your desired result for `i=1,2,3,4,5...`. canging variable names and having same type of multiple function with integer included name is really bad practice

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this isn't exactly the greatest design, you could use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and an `array` containing the method you want to call. In your case, you could do something like:

```
call_user_func(array($menuSet, 'GetMenuLink' . $i));
```

which uses PHP's [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) arrays.

Personally, however, I would recommend refactoring this. Do this processing in the class, in a method named `GetMenuLinks` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a *really* bad design-pattern - **you should avoid it if at all possible**. But it is doable the way you ask it. To do it properly, you should rebuild you function to take an argument which you use, so you have `GetMenuLink(1)` and `GetMenuLink(2)` instead of `GetMenuLink1()` and `GetMenuLink2()`.

```
function getMenuLink($i) {
    // Code for the function goes here
    // Adapt for usage of an arugment, e.g. if ($i == 1) { ... }
    // Use $i to get the link you wish to produce
}
```

---

If that's for some obscure reason not possible, define a variable with the name of the function, and use that as `$variable()`, like shown below. This is called a *variable function*. However, I **strongly** recommend you just rebuild your function to take an argument instead, and avoid a solution like this.

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    $method_name = "GetMenuLink".$i;
    echo "
        <tr>
        <td>$i</td>
        <td>".$menuSet->$method_name()."</td>
        // .....
```

- [PHP variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)
- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/YLQKH)

Answer (score 0):

PHP actually is very liberal in calling functions from variables. I cannot remember what it is called off the top of my head but you can do this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ 
    $func = "GetMenuLink".$i;
echo "
    <tr>
    <td>$i</td>
    <td>".$menuSet->$func()."</td>
    <td>
        <a title='Edit' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>&nbsp; 
        <a title='Remove' href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
";
// replace $menuSet->GetMenuLink1() with another variable
}
```

** *Not sure this is a great idea you may want to look into other patterns though*

Comment: Thank u very very much